# Visual studio 2022 for MAC, Go to Implementation / definition opens assembly browser instead of source code

Tags: visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-mac

When I alt+click / use go to definition / implementation on a class from an external library in VS2022 for MAC. It opens the Assembly browser instead of showing me the code.

If I debug through it and use "go into" I do see the code.

Assembly browser example:

[image: assembly browser]